# How can I activate my virtualenv in visual code terminal?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

How can I activate my virtual environment in visual code terminal? I've tried using the workspace settings method but the settings file was empty

Comment: You can normally use the vscode terminal and activate the environment inside with "source myvenv/bin/activate" as mentioned in the documentation (https://python.land/virtual-environments/virtualenv).

Comment: Please try to search your question on Google or Stackoverflow first. (As a hint, if your question sounds simple enough, it has been almost surely answered multiple times before!) For the sake of completion, the VS code provides [a lot of way to handle python environments](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments)

Answer (score 3):

**Please follow the steps below:**

1. Open your project folder in VS Code
2. Create a new terminal
3. Use the following command in the terminal to create a new virtual environment

   ```py
   # .venv is your virtual environment name
   # You can also use py -3 -m venv .venv
   python -m venv .venv
   ```
4. After the virtual environment is generated, use the following command to activate the virtual environment

   ```
   # .venv is your virtual environment name
   .venv\scripts\activate
   ```

*Normally, when VS Code notices that you have created a new virtual environment, a popup will prompt you to allow it to be selected for the workspace.*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have already created your virtual environment, you can just go to its directory by running the following in the VS Code terminal:

```
cd /python_env/bin/
```

and then

```
source ./activate
```

or, you can directly run

```
source ./python_env/bin/activate
```

from your main project directory.

Comment: it tells me cannot open file

Answer (score 0):

1. Open terminal in VS Code
2. Navigate to your venv environment.For example: cd myvenv
3. For
   **Windows:** .\Scripts\activate
   **Mac:** source bin/activate

You'll see your virtual environment name with parenthesis (myvenv) C:\user\bla\bla